# Packer installation Issues on EC2 Amazon AMI Linux distribution

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, packer

I am having issues installing packer onto the EC2 machine. I have downloaded the Linux packer binary file on my Windows PC and uploaded it to the instance.
I put it into the directory `~/packer_new`, and have been trying two different ways for adding it to the path because it produces this error:

> /usr/share/cracklib/pw_dict.pwd: Permission denied 
>   /usr/share/cracklib/pw_dict: Permission denied

When I run just the `packer` command.

On the packer [website](https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/install.html), it states

> To fix this, you can create a symlink to packer that uses a different name like packer.io, or invoke the packer binary you want using its absolute path, e.g. /usr/local/packer.

I have done the first part by creating a symbolic link using this command:

`sudo ln -s packer_new/packer /usr/bin/packer.io`

And when I run the `packer` command again, it still produces the same error. Am I supposed to be running a different command?

And the second way is to add the path to `~/.bash_profile`:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/packer_new/`

Note that I also have another PATH variable in the bash_profile for bin:
`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin`, not sure if this will affect setting PATH to packer...

But by adding the path, it also produces the same error when running `packer`.

How can I fix this?

One more question, what does it mean when they say:

> invoke the packer binary you want using its absolute path, e.g. /usr/local/packer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And when I run the packer command again, it still produces the same error. Am I supposed to be running a different command?

Run `packer.io` and you link command is wrong. You should do `sudo ln -s $HOME/packer_new/packer /usr/bin/packer.io`

> And the second way is to add the path to `~/.bash_profile`:
>   `export PATH=$PATH:~/packer_new/`

You have to put the path to the front of the `PATH`. I.e.

`export PATH=$HOME/packer_new:$PATH`

> invoke the packer binary you want using its absolute path, e.g. /usr/local/packer.

It means that you can always run with the absolute path. In your case `$HOME/packer_new/packer`.

Comment: I tried `sudo ln -s $HOME/packer_new/packer /usr/bin/packer.io` and it works wonders! Thank you so much.
If anyone is getting a `permission denied` error, don't forget to change the permissions of the packer binary.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue after I installed cracklib-dicts rpm. What worked for me

```
Run->which packer
/usr/sbin/packer
Remove->rm /usr/sbin/packer
sudo ln -s /usr/local/packer /usr/sbin/packer
```

Here is a supporting link for this fix https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/packer/getting-started-install#troubleshooting